# Phonegap + JQM - Phonegap.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am just getting into building a basic app using JQM and Phonegap.

I am using the Phonegap Cloud Builder and so far everything is OK!

But now I want to try and use some of the phones features e.g. the camera. I have read about people doing this successfully using JQM, but the hurdle I am stumbling on involves 'phonegap.js'

As I understand, this file is created typically when a new project is created (using Eclipse of XCode etc). My 'app' is being created by hand (hence using the Cloud Builder) and therefore I have no access to phonegap.js.

All the documentation I find is old and says the files are in the zip download, but they are not. I also figured that the Cloud Builder creates this file, but no idea where it places it in relation to the index page for me to reference it.

So, how can I get hold of the phonegap.js library to use the phones camera, when I am not using an IDE (this is likely to change if there is no way to get the file without one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download PhoneGap here: http://phonegap.com/download/, depending on platform you are developing follow appropriate tutorial included in documentation. Ether way you will be having www folder inside your project with phonegap.js file in it. Copy your jQm web application to www and append phonegap.js file in  of your index.html. Now you will be able to compile native application that can access phone resources.

Comment: Kinda figured it out - seems phonegap.js IS generated when I used the Phonegap:Build service. Normally it would be created when you start a new project in Eclipse or XCode etc.

Comment: old information. there is no such thing as "download" link for phonegap.js any more.